# R ggplot geom_hex alpha transparency

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, transparency, alpha

I have tried to plot some log scale data with geom_hex() but I have a problem with alpha transparency setting.

plot script;

```
p <- ggplot(data =test,aes(x=f.log, y=d.log)) +
        geom_hex(aes(alpha=log(..count..)),fill="#000000")+
        geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = 0.5,color="red",linetype = 2) +
        geom_vline(xintercept = 0, size = 0.5,color="red",linetype = 2) +
        theme_bw()
```

for log scale label correction;

```
p +scale_y_continuous(labels =(math_format(10^.x)))+
   scale_x_continuous(labels =(math_format(10^.x)))
```

test data plot;
[image: Plot 1: Sample data]

Q1: How can I fix the legend label and scales? I used "alpha=log(..count..)", should I use "alpha=..count.."?

Q2: How can I change breaks of the legend? It looks good with "alpha=log(..count..)" but if  I have to use it with "alpha=..count..", I need to define breaks manually.

There is a plot of all data set to show breaks problems;

```
 geom_hex(aes(alpha=log..count..),fill="#000000")
```

[image: Plot 2: All data set in log count format]

```
geom_hex(aes(alpha=log(..count..)),fill="#000000")
```

[image: Plot 3: All data set in log count format]

Thanks,

Data sample;

```
test <- structure(list(
        f.log = c(-0.253102353724454, -0.694948028330518, 
                  -0.016322256625567, -0.0748410768849531, -0.306172135262068, 
                  -0.163707542457202, -0.718554577089733, -0.225934877658866, -0.071806377990495, 
                  -0.571575260001342, -0.0366094797226827, -0.576080377580693, 
                  -0.746006267289661, -0.0489249923859604, -0.80387915691451, 0.133518827725897, 
                  1.13432813432443, -0.0728313199164256, 0.088801860213601, -0.0377135174909077, 
                  0.0663337648981581, -0.888283227909353, 0.00578400013079471, 
                  -0.427522775204275, -0.429431853766945, -0.599421888071496, -0.433485730822919, 
                  -0.515019211162214, -0.0938497739399739, -0.0696149165378972, 
                  -0.365920218802188, -1.1263789720313, -0.0782490805177964, -0.564760702549739, 
                  -0.685258621381461, -0.439931899856536, -0.244258110521373, -0.377736080066162, 
                  0.0948218408558909, -0.315931593580799, -0.410836908516327, -0.00322736005782875, 
                  -0.0340076440089306, -0.196481878570063, -0.272522298650196, 
                  1.37978008331572, -0.292128341834852, -0.378338823768808, -0.0549415716234218, 
                  -0.0420760125426677, -0.40022204799827, -0.225078983984126, 0.0892401574558352, 
                  -0.0973233216952992, -0.0829641774248008, 0.0578619031658385, 
                  -0.310146381039605, -0.999501420674584, 0.00793266670295061, 
                  0.0195285261616878, -0.102208121217403, -0.463412962913123, -0.0422559680343639, 
                  -0.152553959237723, 0.0785955919903926, 0.0624471105838305, -0.0123561431773188, 
                  -0.102918934864132, -0.263458888574933, -0.0998643078923408, 
                  -0.022806867299955, -0.0679252575941792, -0.149199322205565, 
                  -0.0700987795333223, 0.507256549482373, 0.494486856445518, -0.356243129746376, 
                  -0.794907813837392, 0.577206234292617, -0.0328657734578033, -0.0339280520132135, 
                  -0.0208144152712735, -0.297619896483973, -0.798019001203047, 
                  -0.59594523782663, -0.00156810067974492, 0.175299530000646, -0.00188269833802159, 
                  0.00329456016770008, -0.0794669187964468, -0.665134080032122, 
                  0.0956185369659824, -0.233759215904792, -0.180983347256778, -0.234613917607553, 
                  -0.143684236915752, -0.361599738783473, -0.784064624768456, -0.186671650665325, 
                  0.149712456026452), 
        d.log = c(3.16406758837321, 0, 3.80666248977032, 
                  0, 7.74153358928183, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.07944154167984, 
                  0, 0.693147180559945, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.441832752279039, 
                  0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0363676441708748, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8.12740456269308, 
                  0, 0, 3.99951045955126, 1.25276296849537, 0, 0, 0, 6.64378973314767, 
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.934309237376833, 
                  0, 0, 0, 0, -1.09861228866811, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                  0, 4.00733318523247, 0, 0, 0, 7.35179986905778, 0, 0, 0, 1.25276296849537, 
                  2.12026353620009, 0.628608659422374, 0, 4.80402104473326, 0, 
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
        .Names = c("f.log", "d.log"), 
        row.names = c("oncevatan81", 
                      "hatunkotu", "TwitineGeldim", "Kralice_Hanim", "buguzelmi", "DogrulariYaziyo", 
                      "Cokiyibence", "SevimIiGrup", "Sevimli_Dostu", "gununeniyileri", 
                      "SekerGrup_", "RetweetPrensi", "ReTwitPrensesi", "06uzeyirozdemir", 
                      "RTlerim_Ben2", "tanerunal682", "iyibiIgi", "siz_okursunuz", 
                      "adalet1masall", "SevimliRTcisi", "favlasanaa", "SevimliGrup", 
                      "Peter_Dickerson", "TTPrensi", "MrEgosuz", "iyiyazilar", "KelimePerileri", 
                      "DikkatCekici", "TTPrensesi", "scary_hope", "AcimasizTweets", 
                      "34fuzuli34", "guzelmibu", "yenimesajinvar", "ajans_ag", "KralTweets", 
                      "BayEnteresan", "laftrolog", "ilhanerkek", "BiSevsen_", "erosburc", 
                      "fatihalanresmi", "YuruGunese", "dersemneolurr", "SuskunDuvar", 
                      "FenomenTweet", "eneskadam", "SirinSirine", "SevimliGrup_RT", 
                      "filiz_paker", "KizlaraTavsiyem", "EgoSponsoru", "RTMelankolia", 
                      "scary_TT", "Sevimli_Grup", "canEngul", "TheYabani", "Lafeterya", 
                      "MuckBey", "BizimSadece", "cokcokiyi", "SosluMedya", "TTPrensleri", 
                      "SekerGrup", "adalet1masal", "vebirnot", "Alfred_baba", "KadincaRTler", 
                      "Arajman", "KayaSad", "AKTWEET_", "benrtci", "es_es_rt", "sevdamizzz", 
                      "iyiyazarIar", "iyicumIe", "TarzKadin", "YUCELKAR25", "eniyiyazanlar", 
                      "MazlumunFedaisi", "Ak_Ekip_Rte", "hallendik", "b1rTweet", "newrotik61", 
                      "yeryuzusenin", "ResmiZaytung", "MoRHoPi", "Takipci_TayfA", "emre_izmir_", 
                      "SonDakika_Turk", "Karakterm", "KemalAta34", "MakarnaSos", "mustafabilccan", 
                      "SozMekani", "OrijinalRetweet", "CumlelerdeAsk", "sensinmuptezell", 
                      "AforizmaYazar", "FenaYazar"), 
        class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you want to fix? It might be obvious to you, but it is not to me.

Comment: Hi @MikeWise, I need to fix the title of legend which is "log(...count..) and also I need to fix the breaks of the legend which is 10K, 20K...50K in the second plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still not sure what you want, but I looked at the guides. I don't see a way to override how the guide values are printed out, similar to the way you modified the values in the axis. Anyway, this is what I got, using your data above:

```
p <- ggplot(data =test,aes(x=f.log, y=d.log)) +
  geom_hex(aes(fill="#000000",alpha=log(..count..)),fill="#0000ff")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = 0.5,color="red",linetype = 2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, size = 0.5,color="red",linetype = 2) +
  guides(alpha=guide_legend(title="Log of Count",label=T))+
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = (math_format(10 ^ .x))) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = (math_format(10 ^ .x)))

print(p)
```

Yielding this:
 [image]

Comment: Hi @MikeWise, could you use geom_hex(aes(fill="#000000",alpha=..count..),fill="#0000ff") in the script. When you plot it with this line, it gives you 5 and 10 for  count. I would like to change them into 2,4,6,8 and 10. Does it make a sense.

Comment: @eabanoz use the line `scale_alpha_continuous("Log of Count", breaks=seq(2,10,2))` in place of the `guides(...)` line

Comment: Thank @MikeWise for solving break problems at legend. I updated my question so you can see the difference between plot 2 and 3. Plot 3 has a very nice diffusion but legend represent log scale of count instead of this I would like to use linear scale at legend.  I have tried to create plot 3's diffusion with plot 2's legend.