# Plot with darker color for denser areas and transparent color for less dense areas

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I make a plot in R with ggplot2 that is darker where there are more points and more transparent where there are less points? I tried making a geom_hex plot with a gradient but it is ignoring alpha values.

Comment: Can you please include data and/or code that will provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: @BenBolker I just have like 3000+ x y data points.

Comment: you need to set `alpha` and `fill` in the `aes()`

Comment: @RichardTelford I set alpha now transparency is working. What should I set fill to?

Comment: Use fill if you want a colour gradient to enhance the effect of transparency - set it to the same variable

Comment: @RichardTelford Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(x=rnorm(3000),y=rnorm(3000))
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
```

Set alpha on points, natural overlap:

```
ggplot(dd,aes(x,y))+geom_point(alpha=0.1,size=8)
```

(made points larger to get overlap)

Or:

```
ggplot(dd,aes(x,y))+stat_density_2d(geom="raster",
               aes(alpha = ..density..), contour = FALSE)+
     scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
     scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

Still working on `geom_hex` ... I can't actually figure out how to do this ... `aes(alpha=..count..)` seems as though it should work based on [R ggplot geom_hex alpha transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558614/r-ggplot-geom-hex-alpha-transparency) , but ??

```
 ## fails with ggplot 2.1.0 ... ?
 ggplot(dd,aes(x,y))+
     geom_hex(aes(alpha=log(..count..)))
```

Comment: I end up with a much of lines for the second option. Is there any way to make it continuous?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you please include data and/or add code to your question that will provide me with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Never mind. I just had to increase size. It looks great now. Thank you for your help.